# Using Synergy from different platforms with different keymaps, how do I get a semi-predictable result from the target system?

Tags: synergy

I'm running Synergy 1.4.10 on OSX 10.7.5 with a French AZERTY keyboard attached.

When programming, here are the key combinations I have to press on the Mac:

```
 ALT + (          -> {
 ALT + SHIFT + (  -> [
 ALT + )          -> }
 ALT + SHIFT + )  -> ]
 ALT + SHIFT + L  -> |
```

So far so good (well once you get used to programming with that mapping that is :) ).

Now connecting a Synergy 1.4.10 client running on Windows 8 (I don't know whether it's the same with Windows 7)

```
 CTRL + ALT + '  -> {
 CTRL + ALT + (  -> [
 CTRL + ALT + =  -> }
 CTRL + ALT + )  -> ]
 CTRL + ALT + -  -> |
```

Not so surprising, I assume `CTRL + ALT` replaces `AltGr`, though it's unfortunate the `=` key place is totally different on a Mac keyboard compared to a PC keyboard.

So... Instead, is there a chance I keep using say `CTRL + SHIFT + L` and get a `|` displayed when pointer is on the Windows client?

I've always thought Synergy worked by sending characters, hence the following "pipeline":

```
[server]: press ALT+SHIFT+L -> send '|' -> network <- receive '|' <- display '|'
```

---

EDIT: I tried with hotkeys in hope I could make `ALT+SHIFT+L` on one side trigger `AltGr+-` on the other side without success.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the quotes and single quotes when using an international keyboard from Mac 10.8 to Windows 7.

What I ended up doing was adding keyboard shortcuts to windows using [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). It took me a while but I was able to use something like this

```
#0::Send,''{Left}
#9::Send,""{Left}
```

So when pressing Command + 0 I would get a pair of single quotes and the cursor would be in the middle of them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the autohotkey script to make it work:

```
!+L::Send {|}
!+5::Send {[}
!+°::Send {]}
!(::Send {{}
!)::Send {}}
```